# How can I incrementally mirror a Git repository via bundle files?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository on one machine (machine 1) that I would like to keep mirrored on another machine (machine 2). The second machine does not share network access with the first, so simply using `git push` or `git fetch` in one direction or another isn't an option. The repository contains many branches, tags, etc. and I would like to replicate that state exactly onto the second machine. The flow of changes is strictly from machine 1 -> machine 2; I don't have to support bringing commits back the other way.

One approach that works is to use Git bundles. That is, if I do the following:

```
git clone --mirror /path/to/my/source/repo
git bundle create bundle.gitb --all
```

Then the resulting `bundle.gitb` file is a perfect mirror of the source repository. I can then copy this to machine 2 and use it as an origin to push changes into the repository mirror.

The main drawback of this approach is that it requires me to transfer the entire repository history each time. In my case, the history is very deep and is several GB in size, so I have to carry all of that data on every update, even if there are just a few new commits.

Therefore, I would like some kind of incremental Git bundle that only contains the commits that I have yet to transfer to machine 2. Is there a good way to do this?

I considered using the `--since` flag to limit the commits to transfer by commit date, but it's possible that it could cause commits to be missed during the transfer.

- Example: I use `--since=10.days.ago` to get all of the commits in the last 10 days, and I set up the incremental transfer to happen every 10 days. If someone pushes a new branch to the source repository that contains some changes that are older than 10 days, then they will not be included in the next transfer, and they will never make it to machine 2.

I think that in order to meet all of my goals, I would need to be able to provide some kind of manifest of commit SHAs that have already been transferred, and thus I do not want to include in the bundle. So the workflow would be something like:

```
git clone --mirror /path/to/my/source/repo
# do something here to filter out all commits that have already been transferred
git bundle create bundle.gitb --all
```

And the resulting file would just contain the incremental commits. Is there a way to achieve this with one of Git's commands?

Comment: Interesting question. The example in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle#_examples) seems to explain what you need. Did you look at it? Do you need something different?

Comment: I have read that part of the documentation. However, from what I can tell, it only allows me to specify the commits between some particular starting and ending ref. In my case, though, I could have updates on several branches, including forks that haven’t yet been merged back into master, so I don’t think I can easily specify “give me all new new commits since the last transfer” that way.

Comment: The bundle command is essentially half of a `git fetch`: it builds a file that `git fetch` can run the other half of the operation from. You can put *too many* objects into the bundle, if you like. The limiter revisions you give to `git bundle create` just tell it what *not* to put in the bundle, i.e., what you are *sure* the other side already has. So if you're a little unsure, you can put a little too much in, which is OK: it just makes the bundle a little fatter. The more unsure you are, the fatter you should make the bundle.

Comment: The way to get a perfect minimal bundle is to save hash IDs from the source repository, right after running `git bundle`, to remember the revisions that were in the previous bundle. (Where you save them is up to you.) The new bundle is then `--all --not (insert list here)`, after which you generate a new list of revs / hash IDs via `git rev-parse --all` or similar. Alternatively, you can generate the hash IDs from the destination repository, after extracting the bundle there: that's how `git fetch` would do it over a live network connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying this after torek's comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LAST=$(ls | grep \\.bundle$ | sort | tail -n 1)
NEXT=$(date --iso=seconds).bundle
if [ -z "$LAST" ]
then
    git bundle create "$NEXT" --all
else
    git bundle list-heads "$LAST" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs git bundle create "$NEXT" --all --not
fi
```

It uses `list-heads` to output the refs in the last bundle, and `xargs` with `--not` to exclude them from the next bundle.

The documentation for `--all` and `--not` is in `git rev-list --help`.